# Что такое макросы в Лиспе и чем они прекрасны?

Tags: lisp, clojure, scheme

Недавно мне в такой форме наконец таки объяснили ФП. Теперь дело дошло до Лиспа) Можно ли как то быстро объяснить, что такое макросы в Лиспе и чем они прекрасны?

Comment: [История Мака: обычная такая история](http://web.archive.org/web/20150920000632/http://lisper.ru/pcl/macros-defining-your-own)

Comment: Посмотрим, сколько тут писателей-любителей со знанием Lisp

Comment: @avp, Не густо :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Макрос в лиспе - это генератор текста кода программы. 
Прекрасны тем что, пишутся на том же языке, что и сам лисп - никакой новый синтаксис не придумывается. И довольно легко написать код с помощью макроса, который генерирует другой макрос, который в свою очередь генерируется очередным макросом - и т.д. Собственно, это обычная программа в лиспе.
На большинстве распространенных языков это намного труднее и значительно менее наглядно